# How to calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 \cos(ax)e^{-x^2}dx$ using Cauchy's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I want to calculate the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 \cos(ax)e^{-x^2}dx$$
using complex analysis. I have a hint to look at the rectangle $(-R,0), (R,0), (R,h), (-R,h)$ for a certain $h>0$, and use the function $f(z)=z^2e^{az}e^{-z^2}$.

So I wrote down the following paths in order to try using Chauchy's theorem:
$$\gamma_1(t) = t \hspace{1cm} t \in [-R,R]\\
\gamma_2(t) = R + iht \hspace{1cm} t \in [0,1]\\
\gamma_3(t) = -t + ih \hspace{1cm} t \in [-R,R]\\
\gamma_1(t) = -R + ih(1-t) \hspace{1cm} t \in [0,1]$$

Now I get $$\int_{\gamma_1} f(z)dz = \int_{-R}^{R} x^2 \cos(ax)e^{-x^2}dx$$ which is good because if I can calculate the other three integrals, I can send $R$ to $\infty$ and apply Cauchy's theorem.

But how do I calculate integrals like the following?
$$\int_{\gamma_2} f(z)dz = \int_{0}^{1} f(R+iht)(ih)dt$$

Comment: The integrals over the vertical sides tend to $0$ as $R\to \infty$. You need to choose $h$ so that there is a useful relation between the integrals over $\mathbb{R}$ and over $\mathbb{R} + ih$.

Comment: I tried chosing $h=\frac{1}{R}$ but maybe my problem is more elementary. If I look at $\int_{\gamma_2} f(z)dz = \int_0^1 (R+iht)^2 e^{a(R+iht)} e^{-(R+iht)^2}dt$ the integral seems to go to infinity for large $R$ for any $h$. Also I don't see how I can calculate it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some useful things to look out for in the integrals: symmetry properties (some parts are zero because the function is anti-symmetric), Gaussian integrals, chosing $h$ such that difficult parts cancel.